# Python rng in a loop returns the same number all the time

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm running a rng in a loop and using random.choice(list) to pick two words from a list and combine them. I iterate this 300 times, but each time I run it I get the same choice 300 times. If I run the script multiple times I'll get a different choice, but within the loop the choice stays the same. Example:

```
run #1:
    bob alice
    bob alice
    bob alice
    bob alice
run #2:
    john charline
    john charline
    john charline
    john charline
etc...
```

Here's my code:

```
import random

for i in range(1,301): #index starts at 1 for later reasons
    pr = random.choice(pref) #string array containing prefixes
    su = random.choice(suff) #string array containing suffixes
    print (pr + su)
```

I tried using `random.randrange` or `random.randint` but I always get the same problem.

Comment: how are `pref` and `suff` defined?

Comment: show the code for how `pref` and `suff` are defined

Comment: `pref = ["bob", "john", ...]

suff = ["charline", "alice", ...]`

Comment: @Shef - learn providing minimal but functional code here. This not only help others to answer, but often will show you the root of the problem before you have to ask at all.

Comment: Ok. Definition looks fine. This is the problem with randomness. You can never tell.

Comment: @Shef I have tested your code in iPython 2.7 with shortest lists having each only 2 names in there, and I do not see the problem. It is changing. Testing the same in Python 3.4 works also well.

Comment: random seeds from the system time if the seed is not set (unless the system provides sources, such as on linux).  Your loop is executing too quickly and you are seeing the same results.  I would bet money that if you break on that loop and slow it down some (either via debugging or via a sleep timer) you would see the random-ness you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Im not next to my computer right now so i will try it later and update.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon May be you are right (but this is hard to beleive). I would rather expect, Shef has simple bug in the code and prints values, which he had set up before he enters the loop.

Comment: @Shef Could you provide exact script you run? I guess, it does not have too many lines. What OS you run it on? What version of Python?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Definitely need to see more of the code - I ran into this same issue before (albeit years ago and in C#) so it would be very surprising to see it appear now.

Comment: I'm runnin it in Blender, but i removed the blender specific parts due to irrelevance. Maybe that's where my problem is. I'll mark this question as answered for now and see if the problem is in the blender side of things.

Comment: Well the answer prooves that my code "works" outside of blender, so it answers my rng question. I'll test more when i get back to it in two hours, but since the problem is in the blender specific code (bpy) i'll post in the appropriate forums for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that pref is in the form:

```
pref = ['bob', 'suzy', 'dimitri"]
```

and 
    suff = ['smith', 'silvers', 'golds']

`n = 5`

`for i in range(n):
     pr = random.choice(pref)
     su = random.choice(suff)
     print (pr + ' ' + su)`

should get you the answer you need. 
Here is the output I received when I ran this in the terminal.

`joe silvers
alice smith
joe smith
alice smith
bob silvers`

So your code is fine, I guess.  Maybe if you post the entire output, there would be some variations down the list.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the original code works and that the answer is due to an error somewhere else in the code (something blender specific). It works now.